# Remote port forwarding failed on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use [rsub](http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/sublime-tunnel-of-love-how-to-edit-remote-files-with-sublime-text-via-an-ssh-tunnel) on a remote EC2 instance.

I connect to it using

```
ssh -i keyPair.pem -R 52698:localhost:52698 ubuntu@address.amazonaws.com
```

However when I successfully connect to the instance I get the welcoming **error** :

> Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698

The goal of rsub is to set up a tunnel to be able to edit remote files over ssh from my GUI.

Any help with this error is welcome!

The detailed error (`-v`) is:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/victor/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/victor/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-53-211-179.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [52.53.211.179] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/victor/vict0rsch.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/victor/vict0rsch.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a5:e2:ba:33:0a:6a:4b:55:5e:62:8f:1d:d9:bd:eb:9a
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-53-211-179.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/victor/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/victor/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/victor/.ssh/ec2_CS224D_1.pem
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-52-53-211-179.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ([52.53.211.179]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:52698 forwarded to local address localhost:52698
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:52698 forwarded to local address 127.0.0.1:52698
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 52698, connect localhost:52698
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 52698, connect 127.0.0.1:52698
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
debug1: Sending environment.
```

Comment: @l0b0 it should not matter. The port is only on localhost and the way out is "enclosed" in SSH traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 52698, connect localhost:52698
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 52698, connect 127.0.0.1:52698
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 52698
```

It looks like you are trying to open two different port forwarding (`localhost` and `127.0.0.1`), which are basically the same one. Did you set up the forwarding in your `~/.ssh/config` too? Running with `-vvv` might show more information.

It can be also disabled on the server using `AllowTcpForwarding` in `sshd_config`.

Comment: indeed I had forgotten about this one, I had it set up in my ~/.ssh/config also. Cheers

Comment: Tried with `GatewayPorts yes` and `AllowTCPForwarding yes` both the configs in the remote ec2 server still not able to access the local server through the internet but able to access it inside the server terminal. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @ManjunathJakaraddi do you use `localhost` or the actual external IP address of the server?

Comment: actual external public IP address (infact I'm able to access the other applications hosted in the webserver through the same external IP but not the remote port forwarded one)

Comment: @ManjunathJakaraddi what about firewall? Does it allow you to access this port on your machine?

Comment: @Jukuje that is not the problem (turned off the firewall and checked still no success). Currently running a htttp sever locally at port 1234 and `ssh -R 9000:localhost:1234 ec2` using this to remote port forward

Comment: @ManjunathJakaraddi in this command, you use `localhost`, which binds only loopback and therefore is obviously not accessible from outside.

Comment: Even tried with `ssh -R 9000:0.0.0.0:1234 ec2` and the private ip of ec2 also still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221828/discussion-between-manjunath-jakaraddi-and-jakuje).