# I am using Windows and I want to use aws MySQL database by using the following command

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services

`ssh -i "key_pair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-xy-xyz-201-00.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

and I want use DB like cms and I want to use this by using the command

`-L 3000:xyz.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -N`

I am totally confused.

Comment: Are you using RDS or just using a database inside EC2 instance?

Comment: i am using database inside EC2 instance @msvstl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To do local forward(from ec2 to your system)**

```
ssh -i <pem key> -NfL localhost:<your local port>:<instanceip>:<your sql port> <user>@<instance ip>
```

**To do remote forward(from your local system to EC2)**

Make sure `AllowTCPForwarding yes` present in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file by default it's not enabled

Ref: [Remote port forwarding failed on Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963376/remote-port-forwarding-failed-on-amazon-ec2)

```
ssh -i keyPair.pem -R <remote_EC2_port>:localhost:<localhost_port> ec2-user@address.amazonaws.com
```

Also, make sure your EC2 security group allows access to MySql port default(3306)

Comment: bind [127.0.0.1]:3000: Permission denied  
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 3000  
Could not request local forwarding.  How to resolve in windows

Comment: @NikhilKotiya Is your mysql running on 3000? I have updated the answer as well with ports info. chcek once. I didn't try it on windows for your info.

Comment: No like i want to do tunneling of my local db which is on port 3000 with aws port 3306. Now you get it??

Comment: @NikhilKotiya have a look at updated answer